# VsCode markdown: how to add align as a direct math environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, markdown

Basically, I am using vscode for my latex notes due to its snippets, and I would like to have a live preview with markdown. The idea is to take live notes in markdown and then copy and paste them into a latex document to fix all the formatting. I often use the align* environment.

Currently I get
[image]

I want to get (on the right hand side)
[image]

without the dollar signs on the left hand side.
I have found that the tex editor for https://math.stackexchange.com/ does that, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement that in vscode.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in vscode with markdown preview:

```latex
$$
\begin{aligned} 
3     &= 4 \\ 
a + b &= c
\end{aligned}
$$
```

Comment: weird how `align` won't work, but `aligned` does. This seems to be standard tex syntax...